# COUNTIF Function

Tags: excel, countif

I hope you can help me with this.

When I use this formula to check the matches from one column to the main list, instead of showing me that, I get a match when the same word are next to each other (same row).
this is the formula:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(E2, "*"&$D$2:$D$161&"*")), "YES", "NO")
```

It's driving me crazy as I followed the tutorial step by step..

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you do "formula auditing" in order to see when exactly you get the result you don't expect?

Comment: Yes, for each $D$2:$D$161 I get a different name but the results only match when the same word are next to each other.

Comment: Unless you have 365 you need to array enter that with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, or use something like: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(E2, "*"&$D$2:$D$161&"*")), "YES", "NO")`